# Trouble with Firebase persistence feature

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a small app in which users can upload local files to the server.
I am trying to handle unexpected situation like losing Internet connection. I want to use persistence feature which I have declared in AppDelegate.

```
Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
```

At first, I export file to the server and if it succeeds then database reference is created.

```
let uploadTask = ref.putData(contents as Data, metadata: myMetadata, completion: { (metadata, error) in
 if error != nil {
    ...
 } else {
    DataService.instance.usersRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
        ...
    }
   }
)}
```

However, testing the solution (with turning airplane mode on and off) while exporting the file, the transfer is not restored. I am not sure if it's implementation issue or I'm missing key point of persistence feature.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Persistence isn't support for Firebase Storage.  It's only for Firebase Realtime Database.

Comment: check out Ashley Mills' "reachability" on GitHub. When the `whenUnreachable` notification triggers, you could persist it to CoreData and sync it on the next connection.

Comment: Sounds like an answer Doug! :-)

Comment: Try to use Realm